# Bootstrap carousel not responsive in Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I have a problem where Bootstrap carousel will stretch or squish my images inside the carousel when resizing the window. It also stretches my image vertically even when width and height attributes match the size of the image.

I have tried every answer on SO without luck such as setting `min-width: 100%;` to the `.carousel img` class, so on and so forth. My code is straight from the Bootstrap website and I noticed the images inside of it does the same thing.

**The weird thing is that it resizes perfectly to the window in Edge and Firefox.** The images within the carousel look just as intended but opening in Chrome and Opera generates something completely different.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: please share your code

Comment: My code is exactly as follows on the Bootstrap website: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/. I have not added anything extra to it.

Comment: There must be something diff otherwise your code won't have the difference

Answer (score 2):

I think you have specified the height for your Images.

Just make sure to keep height auto and width 100%.

```
.carousel img{ width:100%; height:auto;}
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. My height was at auto.

Comment: have you tried with width:100%; ?

Comment: I've tried everything, I may have targeted the wrong class.

Comment: Ok, the attribute `height: 100%` actually helped me fix this issue. Thanks for the helping though.

Comment: Won't it stretched the image in small device ?

Comment: It scales well with equal ratio after both height and width are set to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 is still in alpha so you can expect some instability. The carousel problem is a known issue in Bootstrap 4.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21611

Comment: Yes, indeed. There are inconsistencies here and there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds not that smart, but use the class "img-responsive" on the img tag's?

```
// Your carousel code ...
<img class="img-responsive .....>
// code ...
```

Which is equivalent to set the max-width of image to 100%